# How to add curve which fits bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I fit the bar chart with a curve similar the density plot for a histogram?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
y<-hist(rnorm(1000),breaks=30)$count

df<-data.frame(x=1:length(y),y=y,key="A")
df2<-data.frame(x=1:length(y),y=y*0.4,key="B")
df<-rbind(df,df2)

p<-ggplot(df,aes(x=x))
p<-p + geom_bar(subset=.(key =="A"),aes(y = y),stat="identity",fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p<-p + geom_bar(subset=.(key =="B"),aes(y = y),stat="identity",fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
#p<-p + geom_density(subset=.(key =="A"), aes(y=y),alpha=.2, fill="#0000FF")
p
```

Comment: using ggplot2? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I want to use ggplot2.

Comment: @Klaus I'm not entirely certain what you want.  Are you simply trying to add a smooth line over the top of the plot for a visual aid or is it line supposed to be calculated in some specific way?  You can add a smoothed line... `p + stat_smooth(aes(y=y, color = key), se = FALSE, span = .3)`

Answer (score 0):

Use *..density..* to do the transformation:

```
data = data.frame(x = rnorm(500))

ggplot(data) + 
geom_histogram(aes(x = x, y = ..density..)) + 
geom_density(aes(x), colour = I('red'))
```

For your data:

```
ggplot(df) +
geom_histogram(aes(y, ..density.., fill=key)) +
geom_density(aes(y, colour = key))
```

And try to avoid names like 'df' (df is a R function i guess)

Comment: This is not an opportunity because later I will combine it with a bar chart like http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-back-to-back-bar-charts/

Comment: I don't know if i get it, but you could replace *geom_histogram* with  *geom_bar(aes(y, fill=key))*

Comment: No that is my problem this is not possible see `p<-ggplot(df,aes(x=x))
p<-p + geom_bar(subset=.(key =="A"),aes(y = y),stat="identity",fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p<-p + geom_bar(subset=.(key =="B"),aes(y = y),stat="identity",fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p<-p+geom_density(aes(y, colour = key))
p
`